# Easily customizable, PXE bootable, ram only Linux Distro?

Tags: linux, iso, ram, pxe

I'm writing a daemon that I'll need to roll into an ISO which can be bootable via PXE by multiple machines simultaneously. This is so I can easily scale a computing operation / expand a pool with zero config.

I'm most familiar with Debian/Ubuntu and Centos systems and prefer to not need to get familiar with a new environment.

Any suggestions for what distro I should start with?